# Displaying legend for two Y axes in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly-python

I am plotting a line chart with two different Y axes using Plotly Express, but only the plots in the primary Y ax are displayed in the legend.

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y":True}]]
pri_line = px.line(df,x, pri_y)
for data in pri_line data:
    fig.add_trace(data, secondary_y=False)
sec_line = px.line(df,x,sec_y)
fig.add_trace(sec_line.data[0], secondary_y=True)
fig.write_html('output.html')
```

The legend should display the plots from both Y axes, but only the plots from the primary ax are displayed.